# comparison of cuda enabled nvidia GPUs

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I would like to state a theoretical question about the compute capabilities of the Nvidia cards.
From my relatively short experience I have noticed that cards with CC 2.0 can perform better than the 1.3 ones. That could really depend on the nature of a kernel and the occupancy each SM will use.

But since everything has its advantages and disadvantages, what are the disadvantages of a 2.0 card and the advantages of a 1.3?

How can a 1.3 card can perform a certain kernel faster than a 2.0 and what characteristics should that kernel have.

Any personal experience is well accepted and if there is a complete interpretation through the architecture of each card even better.

Regards

Comment: Can you edit the question to reflect your question better ? I think you are looking for the comparison between compute capabilities rather than actual GPUs.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the higher the compute capability, the more capabilities the GPU is capable of.
[Check out Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications)

Of course, if you write bad code for a GPU with a CC of 3.5 and great code or GPU with a CC of 2.0, the 2.0 GPU *can* outperform the 3.5 GPU.

Comment: I'm talking about the same piece of code (not the size of the grid) running on a 1.3 and a 2.0. What should the features of the kernel be, as a result to perform faster on a 1.3.

Comment: This is not possible. 2.0 is superior to 1.3 in all parameters. The most likely answer to your question is that if the size of the data set does not fit into equally divisible blocks, then you end up with more threads than are needed and possibly extra kernel invocations. However since a 2.0 cc device has more blocks, larger dimensionality, more threads per block, etc. you cannot outperform a 2.0 cc device with a 1.3 device.

Comment: @slcott... Yes you can outperform a 2.0 device with a 1.3 device in terms of performance. Try running a piece of code on Tesla C1060 (CC 1.3) and the same code on GeForce GT 440 (CC 2.1). Guess which one would be faster? Number of cores and clock speed of the device are the major parameters which decide the speed of a code.

Comment: Compute capability 2.x is inferior to 1.x with regard to the possible number of registers per thread (127 vs 63), which can be very useful e.g. in matrix multiplication. Apart from that, the most powerful 1.x device (GTX 285 with 20 SMs) certainly was more powerful that the low end of 2.x devices (e.g. GTX 430 with 2 SMs).